# How to bypass a input file when is not uploaded in VueJS/Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, axios, vuejs3

I'm making a VueJS blog; I'm working with the update page and everything is working except the input file field: It works only if you'll upload a file, if you don't upload it the console return this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData':
> parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

Else, I've tried to make an if state with a variable and a boolean field but in this way the image never uploads (but it not gave any error in console and it make the form working if you don't upload an image). I'll put below the code with and without the if statement. The Backend is  made with Django and Django Rest framework.

**VueJS without the If statement (1st example)**

```
<template>
    <main>
        <SideBar></SideBar>
        <section>
            <h3>Edit {{ form.title }}</h3>
            <form @submit.prevent = "onSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titolo" v-model="form.title">
                <input type="text" name="category" v-model="form.category">
                <textarea type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Descrizione" v-model="form.desc"> </textarea>
                <textarea name="text" v-model="form.text"></textarea>
                <input type="file" name="image" @change="EditImage">
                <input type="text" name="author" v-model="form.author">
                <input type="text" name="author" v-model="form.slug">
                <button type="submit">Edit</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </main>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { getAPI } from '../api'
import SideBar from '../components/Admin/Sidebar.vue';
import swal from 'sweetalert'
export default {
    components: { 
        'SideBar': SideBar
    },
    data () {
        return{
            Postslug: this.$route.params.Postslug,
            form: {
                title:"",
                desc:"",
                text:"",
                category:"",
                date:"",
                author:"",
                image:"",
                slug:"",
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        EditImage(event){
            this.form.image = event.target.files[0]
        },
        // Form method
        onSubmit(event, imageSelection){
            console.log(imageSelection);
            const fd = new FormData();

            fd.append('title', this.form.title)
            fd.append('desc', this.form.desc)
            fd.append('text', this.form.text)
            fd.append('category', this.form.category)
            fd.append('date', this.form.date)
            fd.append('author', this.form.author)
            fd.append('image', this.form.image, this.form.image.name)   
            fd.append('slug', this.form.slug)

            // event.preventDefault();     
            axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/api/edit/${this.Postslug}`, fd).then(response => {
              this.form.title = response.data.title
              this.form.desc = response.data.desc
              this.form.text = response.data.text
              this.form.image = response.data.image
              this.form.category = response.data.category
              this.form.author = response.data.author
              this.form.slug = response.data.slug
              
              this.$router.push({ name: 'AdminEditArticle', params: {Postslug: this.form.slug } });
              
              swal("Articolo editato", "", "success")
              .then(() => {
                  window.location.reload()
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    swal("Problema", "", "warning")
                });
              })

            .catch(err => {
            })
        },
    },
    
    created() {
        getAPI.get(`blog/api/edit/${this.Postslug}`)
            .then(response => {
              this.form.title = response.data.title
              this.form.desc = response.data.desc
              this.form.text = response.data.text
              this.form.date = response.data.date
              this.form.image = response.data.image
              this.form.category = response.data.category
              this.form.author = response.data.author
              this.form.slug = response.data.slug
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
        },
    name: 'AdminEditArticle',
}

</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
stuff...
</style>
```

**Code with the if statement (2nd example)**

```
<template>
    <main>
        <SideBar></SideBar>
        <section>
            <h3>Edit {{ form.title }}</h3>
            <form @submit.prevent = "onSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Titolo" v-model="form.title">
                <input type="text" name="category" v-model="form.category">
                <textarea type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Descrizione" v-model="form.desc"> </textarea>
                <textarea name="text" v-model="form.text"></textarea>
                <input type="file" name="image" @change="EditImage">
                <input type="text" name="author" v-model="form.author">
                <input type="text" name="author" v-model="form.slug">
                <button type="submit">Edit</button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </main>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import { getAPI } from '../api'
import SideBar from '../components/Admin/Sidebar.vue';
import swal from 'sweetalert'
let imageSelection = false;
export default {
    components: { 
        'SideBar': SideBar
    },
    data () {
        return{
            Postslug: this.$route.params.Postslug,
            form: {
                title:"",
                desc:"",
                text:"",
                category:"",
                date:"",
                author:"",
                image:"",
                slug:"",
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        EditImage(event){
            this.form.image = event.target.files[0]
            let imageSelection = true
            return imageSelection
        },
        // Form method
        onSubmit(event, imageSelection){
            console.log(imageSelection);
            const fd = new FormData();

            fd.append('title', this.form.title)
            fd.append('desc', this.form.desc)
            fd.append('text', this.form.text)
            fd.append('category', this.form.category)
            fd.append('date', this.form.date)
            fd.append('author', this.form.author)
            if (imageSelection == true) {
             fd.append('image', this.form.image, this.form.image.name)   
            }
            fd.append('slug', this.form.slug)

            // event.preventDefault();     
            axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/api/edit/${this.Postslug}`, fd).then(response => {
              this.form.title = response.data.title
              this.form.desc = response.data.desc
              this.form.text = response.data.text
              this.form.image = response.data.image
              this.form.category = response.data.category
              this.form.author = response.data.author
              this.form.slug = response.data.slug
              
              this.$router.push({ name: 'AdminEditArticle', params: {Postslug: this.form.slug } });
              
              swal("Articolo editato", "", "success")
              .then(() => {
                  window.location.reload()
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    swal("Problema", "", "warning")
                });
              })

            .catch(err => {
            })
        },
    },
    
    created() {
        getAPI.get(`blog/api/edit/${this.Postslug}`)
            .then(response => {
              this.form.title = response.data.title
              this.form.desc = response.data.desc
              this.form.text = response.data.text
              this.form.date = response.data.date
              this.form.image = response.data.image
              this.form.category = response.data.category
              this.form.author = response.data.author
              this.form.slug = response.data.slug
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
            })
        },
    name: 'AdminEditArticle',
}

</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
stuff...
</style>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to save an image with your form.
For this to work, you should first upload the file and then take the imagePath(where you uploaded it) and save the path in your form.

So in your submit function, you should make a post request to upload the image and take the response which will be the image path on your server and save it in your form object.

Example :

```
onSubmit() {
  if(checkIfCreateOrEdit)
       createPost(this.form).then(res => {
             if (this.form.image instanceof File) {
                 const formData = new FormData()
                 formData.append('imagePhoto', this.form.image)
            return axios.post(url, headers: 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data', data: formData)
                
 
          })
          .then(()=> this.$router.push(....) )
          .catch(....)
} else {
    editPost(this.form, this.post.id){
             .....the same as above but you make a put request based on the id
             }
}
```

Notes:
Try to use destructure on your form object.
In order to show the image on your template after you have submitted the form, you should recreate the imagePath and pass it as src attribute.

Comment: I've tried but I did not make the code work, how to do that? (sorry but i'm not good at Vue )

Comment: I edited my original post with a semantic example, i hope it helps more